# Limiting the input of one str[n]

Tags: c++, string, input

I am having trouble with a console application I have to make. The problem is that I have a void function, in which I use `cin.getline` from `<iostream>` and `<cstring>`.

My string is defined like this: `char str[50];` and everytime I enter more than 50 symbols i get into an infinite loop and basically my program crashes.

Can any of you think of a function that ignores everything past the limit (in this case 50) so that my program wont crash. By ignores, I mean that when I enter 50+ symbols, the program says:

> max 50 symbols, please input again:

Comment: Why not `std::string`?

Comment: Maybe add some of your code so you can get a feedback on what you already done.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `std::getline` instead of `istream.getline`. `std::getline` works with std::string and does not need a preallocated buffer.

If you need the 50 char limit just check the string size after reading the whole line into the string.

Answer (score 1):

The second signature of getline

```
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
```

is likely what you're after.  The `streamsize n` parameter is what you're looking for.  [This documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) might help.  Don't forget to check the failbit.

As others have mentioned, using std::string is a much better solution, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and assume you have a reason for allocating a static c-style char buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the limited `cin.getline(char* s, int maxsize)`
the getline return if the maxsize limit of input character is reached.

see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/